# Sampling from a multivariate distribution including gender in R

Tags: r, simulation, covariance

I'm trying to simulate a wider population from a small one in R as follows:

```
idata <- subset(data, select=c(WT, AGE, HT, BFP, SEX) )
M= cor(idata)
mu <- sapply(idata, mean)
sd <- sapply(idata, stdev)
sigma=cor2cov(M, sd)
simulation <- as.data.frame(mvrnorm(1000, mu, sigma))
```

But the problems is, for SEX, the code will consider a continuous distribution, while it has to be binary, and effects of sex has to be either fully considered (SEX==1), or not at all (SEX==0). I'd appreciate any help with this regard.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is consider that your data consists of two sub-populations, and then draw data from them, based on their proportions.

So, first estimate the proportions, `pi_m` and `pi_f (= 1 - pi_m)`, which are the proportion of SEX == 0 and SEX == 1. This should be something like
`pi_m = sum(idata$SEX == 1)/ nrow(idata)`

Then estimate parameters for the two populations, `mu_f`, `mu_m`, `sigma_f` and `sigma_m`, which are mean and covariance parameters for the two SEX populations (now without the SEX variable).

The first draw a random number `r <- runif(1)`, if this is less than equal to pi_m  then generate a sample from `N(mu_m, sigma_s)` else from `N(mu_f, sigma_f)`.

You can do this step 1000 times to get 1000 samples from your distribution.

Of course, you can vector this, by first generating 1000 samples from `runif`. For example

```
n_m <- sum(runif(1000) <= pi_m)
n_f <- 1000 - n_m

X_m <- rmvnorm(n_m, mu_m, sigma_m)
X_f <- rmvnorm(n_f, mu_f, sigma_f)

X <- rbind(X_m, X_f)
```

Comment: Maybe you could make the answer explicit by saying that in order to vectorize the OP would then use `ifelse` to generate from each normal.

Comment: I have added some code at the end. I think it effectively does the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is certainly helpful when there's significant number of each subpopulation. In this specific problem, there are more than one type of binary data, (e.g. patient frailty(0,1),  hepatic dysfunction (0,1)), and some of the categories don't have enough population to attribute it to a normal distribution. Is it inevitable and I have to practically break it down into 8 subpopulations? Only if there was a multivariate sampler which accounted for binary variables.

Comment: @AlAbadi There are type of models called location models which deals with data with both continuous and categorical variables.

Comment: Yes, even better than `ifelse`.